# Access TFS from Azure Service

Tags: asp.net, azure, tfs

In my application, I have to show the work items of logged in user. I have tried to pull work items of TFS from the application and It’s working fine on local server, but when it is deployed to the cloud server, it is not working and getting error message saying ‘TF400324 : The remote name could not be resolved’, as a cloud application is trying to ping internal TFS.

Is there any way to connect to internal TFS from the application hosted on cloud server ?

Many thanks in advance..

Comment: If your TFS server is not exposed externally, how do you want to access it? By local machine name? Or do you have a public http endpoint?

Comment: I do not have a public http endpoint. I think, my cloud service VM need to be enabled for accessing corporate network with the help of  VPN and will be required to be domain joined with on-premise domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple tries, Service Bus Relay Binding is the one, to ping on-premise environment(internal tfs) from azure cloud server(web role).

The below link works like charm.. 
[Service Bus Relay Binding](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-relay/)

Hope It Helps to Somebody who has faced the same issue I've faced. Have Fun..

Answer (score 2):

You can setup an Azure VPN tunnel between your cloud service and your internal network:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-network/

Or you could expose your internal TFS to the internet:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668967.aspx

Or you could use the Azure BizTalk Hybrid Connections to enable the communication:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/integration-hybrid-connection-overview/